# 'At your own risk' or 'On your own risk'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I think these sentences are grammatical:

> Try this company *on* your own risk.
>   
>   Read *on* your own risk. 
>   
>   Watch it *on* your own risk.

But then...

> Parking *at* your own risk?

I'm confused using a preposition when it comes to *our own risk.* If I consider the preposition *at* emphasizing on *parking* (a place and hence *at*) but then here **pre** positioning is for 'own risk' and not the place (parking).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The choice of preposition has nothing to do with the word *parking*.

You can only do something *at* [a] risk, not **on* [a] risk.  Any of the following would be non-standard with **on* in place of *at*:

> - put your family *at* risk
> - it's impossible to predict exactly which cities are *at* the greatest risk for hurricanes
> - becoming a lion tamer *at* the risk of being eaten by a lion
> - as a smoker, she is *at* high risk of developing lung cancer
> - jumping over Springfield Gorge *at* considerable risk to life and limb
> - high blood pressure puts you *at* risk for a stroke
> - he is an *at*-risk student
> - *at* great risk
> - *at* your own risk
> - they remain *at* substantial risk

The OED puts this use under "of conditioning circumstance", grouping *at risk* with such other combinations as *at great expense*, *at an advantage*, *at a disadvantage*, and *at their peril*.

Like many preposition combinations, this is one you'll have to memorize.

---

*In this answer, the* * *symbol indicates non-standard English.*

Comment: I see that * should be used as a prefix, and there is obvious justification for that. If ? replaces *, it won't be confused for punctuation, and a prefix gives the earliest indication (in the left to right sense) that the item is considered ungrammatical.

Comment: @snailboat. http://www.huffingtonpost.ca/2012/03/28/rescuers-pluck-13-america_n_1385301.html where *an American fisherman* uses it. I think it's rarest rare case then.

Comment: @MaulikV *Non-standard* doesn't mean "no one ever says it".  After all, a lot of people say "ain't", but it's considered non-standard anyway--it's not accepted by educated users of English as part of the standard language.  Likewise, people use double negatives for emphasis all the time ("I ain't got no money" meaning "I have no money at all"), but this is non-standard as well.  In any case, what the American fisherman has said there is quite rare; there's no reason why *on* wouldn't make sense, but nonetheless very few people say it that way and it's not accepted as standard.

Comment: @snailboat. Okay, got it. That's what I said in my comment. It seems rarest rare (and thus, not a standard way).

Answer (score 3):

The phrase is fixed as ***at your own risk***; native English speakers will almost never say "on your own risk":

[image]

Comment: This is also the first time I heard "on your own risk". A confusion with "on your own", maybe? Remembering the phrase "at risk" might help.

Comment: Nope, not confused with 'on your own'. I have observed this in speeches/statements.

> http://www.wattpad.com/12448111-a-bit-too-sassy-louis-tomlinson-chapter-3-~

>http://www.huffingtonpost.ca/2012/03/28/rescuers-pluck-13-america_n_1385301.html - though this is the statement but spoken by an American. In fact, the news is about American fishermen.

Comment: I just googled "on your own risk" (with quotation marks), and I got over 300 million results. That says something. ("at your own risk" returned 800 million results.) Is this a new trend?

Comment: Some native speaker told me (and he's right!) stop believing Google unless it's Google Books. It's flooded with an odd dialect of English! :(

Comment: @DamkerngT. Be careful with Google's hit count - it's incredibly approximate, and based on something like the linear addition of the number of results for each word in turn. For me, I get told there's 201million results for "on your own risk", but 32 pages into actually *listing* the results, Google runs out, so I suspect the 201m number is not a good number to rely on.

Comment: @MaulikV - True on that! A straight Google search will find hits in message boards, blogs, memes, news comments, Twitter feeds, and restaurant reviews. The internet is incredible – now everyone in the world has a voice! Unfortunately, though, not every chooses to speak grammatically when they decide to speak up (or heed their spell checker, even). [Quite the contrary](https://www.google.com/#q=%22know+way+that+happens%22).

Comment: @MaulikV Those examples aren't Standard English.

Comment: The occurrence of the 4-gram "on your own risk" in the data doesn't prove that this is actually a linguistic unit. For instance "your own risk" could be the beginning of a longer noun phrase, which is not a kind of risk, e.g.: "The same threat appears *on your own risk* profile".